# Installing native libraries to Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have only APK file and I can't edit it. I tried to install the file to emulator, but I caught the error - INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS. The error means that there is no native libraries on the emulator. How can I install native libriries to emulator or solve the issue using another way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the image your are using for your emulator ?. Secondly, if you are using Genymotion you need to install ARM Translation and GApps

Comment: What does it mean the image? I am using Android studio emulator, not Genymotion.

Comment: The system image with wich you have created the emulator.

Comment: I added the image above

Comment: I tried to use Genymotion with ARm and GApps. It's work. Thank you. Link how to install -  https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en. Also, I started arm64 using Android studio emulator, it's work but very slowly.

Comment: Happy to hear that :) and thanks for the link. To optimize the speed, i suggest using Linux if you haven't already. Google also has a better virtualization on Linux (in case you switched back to Android Emulator).